# How to disable Steam-Play (linux) Notification about proton when launching a game

Tags: linux, steam-play

Anytime you launch a game in steam that uses the SteamPLay feature a popup is displayed warning you about the compatibility tool (image)

[image: steam-play notification]

Is there a way to disable this notification?

Comment: This only happens the very first time I do that. Does it really happen for you always?

Comment: Just the very first time but it  breaks the BigPicture sofa experience since you have to stand up and go to the computer.. Even worse if you use SteamLink hence the question.

Comment: I don't have to do that either. If I launch a game from BP, there's either no dialog or I can use my gamepad to control it.